# ruby code: why put colon in front of variable name (inside initialize method)

Tags: ruby

I came across some Ruby code,
I try to understand why the variables have colon at the end of their name inside the declaration of the `initialize` method.

Is there any reason for the colon?

```
attr_reader :var1, :var2

def initialize(var1:, var2:)
   @var1 = var1
   @var2 = var2
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are keyword arguments.

You can use them by name and not position. E.g.

```
ThatClass.new(var1: 42, var2: "foo")
```

or

```
ThatClass.new(var2: "foo", var1: 42)
```

[An article about keyword arguments by thoughtbot](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments)

Answer (score 5):

It is called [keyword arguments](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments).

> Keyword arguments are similar to positional arguments with default
>   values:
>
> ```
> def add_values(first: 1, second: 2)
>   first + second
> end
> ```
>
> Arbitrary keyword arguments will be accepted with **:
>
> ```
> def gather_arguments(first: nil, **rest)
>   p first, rest
> end
>
>
> gather_arguments first: 1, second: 2, third: 3
> # prints 1 then {:second=>2, :third=>3}
> ```
>
> When calling a method with keyword arguments the arguments may appear
>   in any order. If an unknown keyword argument is sent by the caller an
>   ArgumentError is raised.
>
> When mixing keyword arguments and positional arguments, all positional
>   arguments must appear before any keyword arguments.